# Can i play music on mpd from the controlling device?

Tags: linux, mpd

Im running mpd server on a Pi 3 and use my laptop and a mpd client to play music on the Pi. I can play music stored on the Pi but can I also use mpd to play music stored on the device that is running the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [The mpd client protocol](https://www.musicpd.org/doc/html/protocol.html) does not provide any way to upload content -- the music files must be present on the computer running mpd.

Comment: Any ideas for a workaround that lets me use smartphone and laptop to play files from the device on a remote server?

Comment: Well, it allows you to add stream URLs, so technically you could make it play files over SMB...